# Technical question in computing the current density of BCS Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, superconductivity

I came across with the following question in reading Altland and Simons CMFT:

Consider the BCS Hamiltonian

$S[\bar{\psi},\psi] = \int_0^{\beta} d \tau \int d^d r [\bar{\psi}(\partial_{\tau} +ie\phi + \frac{1}{2m} (-i \nabla -eA)^2 - \mu ) \psi - coupling\ terms]$

Then the author compute the current density with respect to it.

$j = \frac{\partial S}{\partial A} = - \frac{e}{2m} [\bar{\psi} (-i \nabla - A ) \psi + (i \nabla - A)\bar{\psi} \psi]$

Now I can’t figure out how does the author get this result, it seems to me that there should be two $(-i\nabla -A)$ terms in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variation of vector potential $\delta A$ leads to the following linear part of the variation of the action
$$
\delta S = \int d\tau d^d r\, \overline{\psi}\frac1{2m}\left(-e\delta A(-i\nabla-eA)-e(-i\nabla -eA) \delta A\right)\psi
$$
In the second term in parentheses the differential operator $\nabla$ acts on $\delta A \psi$. $\delta A$ is a function of $\tau$ and $r$. To write a variational derivative of action, one should integrate by parts and rewrite $\delta S$ in the following form
$$
\delta S = \int d\tau d^dr\, \delta A\left(-\frac{e}{2m}\right)\left(\overline{\psi}(-i\nabla -eA)\psi +(i\nabla-eA)\overline{\psi}\psi\right)
$$
The last equality gives for $\delta S/\delta A$ the expression from the book.

Comment: Thanks! Btw in the result the $\nabla$ is operating on $\bar{\Psi}$ only right? Since through integration by part we take $\delta A \Psi$ as a whole outside.

Comment: @JiahaoFan Yes, in the second term, $\nabla$ operates only on $\overline{\psi}$.